# Doctrine One to Many relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many

I got confuse in doctrine one to many relationship.

**Question 1:**

Correct me if I am wrong. I assume that when I try to

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$product_repo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product');
$products = $product_repo->findAll();
dump($products);
```

I will see the related features attached to the $features variable, so when I use $products->getFeatures() I will have Feature object in array form. But from the dump debug I didn't not see anything attached to it instead I got this:

[image]

On the other end I also do this

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$feature_repo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Features');
$features = $product_repo->findAll();
dump($features);
```

This time I can see the Product object is attached to the $product variable.

**My question is, is there any problem why I can't get data from the variable $features? Or doctrine wouldn't load the related data by default.**

**Question 2:**

If we were assumed that the data is able to load into the feature $variable, is it possible that I can filter the data (eg. where feature.name = 'fly') instead of load all of the related feature.

==========================================================================

**My Demo Entity**

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity **/
class Product
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="product")
     **/
    private $features;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->features = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity **/
class Feature
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="features")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $product;
    // ...
}
```

**Product table (in database):** id, description, name

**Feature table (in database):** id, description, name, table_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your dump function is symfony/var-dumper and not a custom function

### Question 1

Yes, nested collection are not displayed by default by dump function, its about performance. This is not a Doctrine related issue. Your data are loaded here.

You can play around with advanced use of var-dumper, like casters ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/advanced )

### Question 2

You have differents ways to solve your question :

#### In Controller : Create your custom method in Product

**Criteria** better solution

```
Product::getFeaturesByName($name='fly'){
  $criteria = Criteria::create();
  $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('name', $name));
  return $this->features->matching($criteria);
}
```

**Filter**

```
Product::getFeaturesByName($name='fly'){

  return $this -> features ->filter(
      function($entry) use ($name) {
         return $entry->getName() == $name;
      }
  );
}
```

);
    }

#### In Twig Template : filter in loop

```
{% for product in products %} {# start browse products #}
  {% for feature in product.features if feature.name='ok' %}{# start browse features #}

  {% endfor %}{# end browse features #}
{% endfor %}{# end browse products #}
```

Hope this will help you

regards

Comment: Thank you very much, you have same my day. I got other question about question 2, is all those method you listed here will load the specific value I entered or it will still load all the value from db and do filtering on the program?

Comment: By Criteria is the most optimized solution: If the collection was not loaded from db, it will select only Entity matching the criteria. By filters or twig solution load all data form db and do filter on "program".